# Axios method is passing item as null, instead of the actual value to my mongoose route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, redux, axios

My Axios method is passing the item.GroupID as Null it seems, it successfully finds the item in my database using the item.id however.

Axios Method:

```
export const updateGroupID = item => dispatch => {
  axios.post(`/api/users/${item.id}/update`, item.GroupID).then(
    res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GROUPID_UPDATE,
        payload: res.data
      }),
    console.log(item.id)
  );
};
```

Mongoose Route:

```
router.post("/:id/update", (req, res) => {
  Users.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      $set: { GroupID: req.body.GroupID }
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, user) => {
      console.log("Triggered Update");
      if (err) res.send(err);
      else res.send("Account GroupID Updated" + " " + user);
    }
  );
});
```

How I'm calling the Axios method in React:

```
<button onClick={()=> {
      const updatedID = {
         id: this.props.user.user.UserId,
           GroupID: this.state.GroupID
      };
      this.props.updateGroupID(updatedID);
      }}
>join group</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios by default will serialize requests as JSON, but you dont pass a valid JSON payload i.e.

```
axios.post(`/api/users/${item.id}/update`, item.GroupID)
```

Should be

```
axios.post(`/api/users/${item.id}/update`, { GroupID: item.GroupID })
```